Ryzen 7 7840HS onboard GPU and second life
Radeon 780M on-die GPU
It doesn't work very well in second life. It  hangs, and when it works for a little while, then it hangs. It doesn't do that in Google Earth. Those are the only 3D apps I use. My 5.2 GHz CPU is one of the fastest you can get, and it's not loaded. No other apps running.
Win 11, Avast driver scan update every day.
Note that with the latest release, second life completely redid their graphics I/O system to bring it up to modern standards. Like, now they can do mirror reflections.
Does anyone have any ideas? I was  gonna get an external PCIe bus extender, but they're 600 bucks.

Second Life should run fine with anything from almost 15 years ago. Same for Google Earth. Which OS? And, if Windows, are your AMD graphics drivers updated? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

You don't need and arguably shouldn't use any 3rd party software to install/update drivers. For AMD graphics drivers in Windows it's always recommended to install the proprietary drivers from AMD: https://www.amd.com/en/support/download/drivers.html

I do. the software just makes sure that I have the latest one.

I guess you have a pretty good  reason for avast, but what happens if you disable it, and just run defender? I've (barely) run AAA games (with poor frame rates) on less. Also, can you turn down your graphics settings somewhat?
